# Trying to convert color in string format t use in switch case

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to convert color in string format to use in switch case to check the color which is filled in ellipse and based on that i want to fill the color in ttf icon. On Tapped Event of"Header_P" i want to check the color with which Ellipse "chkColor" is filled and with same color i want to fill "colorimg" ttf icon with same color

Xaml

```
 <Image x:Name="Header_P" 
            Source="Assets/Paint/bg_paint_sub.png"              
               Height="250" Width="600"
              RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
               Margin="0,60,40,0"
                   Opacity="0.8"
                   Tapped="Header_P"
               />
            <Ellipse x:Name="chkColor" Height="40" Width="40"
                     RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
                     RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                     Margin="0,140,235,0"></Ellipse>
    <TextBlock x:Name="colorimg"
            Text="0" TextAlignment="Center" 
                   RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"                  
                   FontFamily="Font/fill-icons.ttf#fill-icons"
                   FontSize="170"
                   Margin="0,90,50,0"/>
```

c# code

```
private void Header_P(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string colorn = chkColor.GetValue();
    switch ()
    {
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use `chkColor`'s Fill property?

Comment: @Abion47 you mean like this

Comment: string colorn = chkColor.Fill.ToString();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet extracts the color from the Brush if it is a SolidColorBrush.

```
private void Header_P(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var colorBrush = chkColor.Fill as SolidColorBrush;
    if (colorBrush != null)
    {
        colorimg.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(colorBrush.Color);
    }
}
```

Comment: what need to be written in c# side on "Header_P"  image tapped event which should filled the color in ttf image

Comment: Do you want to apply the color only after a Tap event ?

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done through XAML instead of code behind using **Behaviours**

Behaviors SDK is not built-in UWP, but has to be downloaded separately from NuGet.

Install the NuGet Package for `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed`.

After you install, you can just add the XAML using statements to the top of your page:

```xml
<Page ...
xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:Core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core" />
```

and change your `Header_p` to below.

```
<Image x:Name="Header_P" Source="Assets/Paint/bg_paint_sub.png" Height="250" Opacity="0.8" >
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped" SourceObject="{Binding ElementName=chkColor, Mode=OneWay}" >
            <Core:EventTriggerBehavior.Actions>
                <Core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Foreground" TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=colorimg}" Value="{Binding Fill, ElementName=chkColor}"/>
            </Core:EventTriggerBehavior.Actions>
        </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Image>
```